# Torrent traffic blocked in Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, qbittorrent

I recently switched my local machine from Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu server (realized I wasn't using the gui anymore, so decided to go with a fresh install and test my skills).

Everything is going well except I can't get qBittorrent to connect to any trackers. Every torrent (including official Ubuntu iso torrents) just says "Errored". Same issue occurs when I install from repositories as well as in docker compose. My windows machine on the same home netowrk can connect and download just fine.

Ports are forwarded at the router. Listening ports in the qBit webUI are set to the same as the router. UFW is turned off. User has r/w/x permissions on all config and download directories. I am at a loss to explain it. Any help would be appreciated.